# How to patch standard header <memory> to work with -fno-rtti compiler option

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc4.4

I am trying to use std::unique_ptr on gcc4.4.x, but facing issues regarding `shared_ptr.h` compilations. `shared_ptr.h` can't be compiled with `-fno-rtti` compiler options.

I don't need std::shared_ptr, I am just using `std::unique_ptr` and some old code still uses `std::auto_ptr`.

Can I patch header `<memory>` to ensure that `shared_ptr.h` does not get compiled when somebody includes `<memory>`. Currently I am using `-DSHARED_PTR_H=1` in compiler options to avoid compiling `shared_ptr.h`. Which seems quite a hack, can you please direct me to a better approach?

Comment: Better approach?  Get a modern compiler and std library (and build as C++14). And nuke those `auto_ptr`s from orbit. Ohh and just learn to live with RTTI - it's not so bad, really.

Comment: I am not that lucky man, I have to live with these old compilers on embedded platforms. :( And a customer is really adamant with `-fno-rtti`. Hope you understand.